# How do I dump a text node with inline link targets in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have some HTML like:

```
<span class="foo">foo bar <a href="http://example.com">example</a> baz</span>
```

and I'd like to turn it into a string like:

```
foo bar http://example.com baz
```

I'm using Nokogiri and I've got something like:

```
doc.css('.foo').each do |message|
  message.css('a').map {|link| link.replace(link['href'])}
  message.xpath('.//text()').map do |m|
    p m.text
  end
end
```

but that seems to put out:

```
foo bar
http://example.com
baz
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `puts (message.xpath('.//text()').map { |m| m.text }).join " "` instead.

As a general comment on style, you're using `map` in the wrong context. `Map` applies a block to all elements of an enumerable, returning back those modified items. In this context, you're using `map` where you should be using `each`.

Comment: That looks like it would work, I ended up putting a variable outside the inner loop and appending to inside then printing it after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p m.text` will insert a newline after each line of text, but the document itself doesn't have any of the newlines. Simply print out `message.text`, and you should get what you want.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(DATA.read)
doc.css('.foo').each do |message|
  message.css('a').each {|link| link.replace(link['href'])}
  puts message.text # prints "foo bar http://example.com baz"
end

__END__
<span class="foo">foo bar <a href="http://example.com">example</a> baz</span>
```